# R won't read in numeric values of CSV in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, number-formatting

I am a beginner in R, so please bear with me! I have a csv read into R, it shows the relative abundance of different species at 9 sites. I am trying to get a summation of the rows, however R will not read the numerical values as such, which is going to lead to more issues as I try to run an NMDS ordination analysis. Here are some details about my data:

```
class(MSBees.spp)

[1] "data.frame"
```

First few rows of what `str()` prints:

```
str(MSBees.spp)  

'data.frame':   9 obs. of  29 variables:  
 $ X     : chr  "Site 1" "Site 2" "Site 3" "Site 4" ...  
 $ COLALG: num  0.02013 0.00997 0 0 0 ...  
 $ COLCAL: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  
 $ COLCON: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0.00339 0 0  
 $ COLFUL: num  0 0 0 0 0 0.00361 0 0 0  
 $ COLOBS: num  0.00671 0.00664 0.00755 0.00292 0 ...
```

What my code looks like so far:

```
MSBees.spp <- read.csv("data_transposed.csv", header = TRUE)   
MSBees.env <- read.csv("data_transposed.env.csv", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)   
MSBees_PA.spp <- read.csv("data_transposed.csv", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)  
MSBees_abund.spp <- read.csv("data_transposed.csv", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)   
sum.of.rows <- apply(MSBees.spp, 1, sum)
```

which returns:
*Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument*

I have tried to coerce them to be numeric with:

```
as.numeric (MSBees.spp)
```

and

```
data.frame(lapply(MSBees.spp [2:9, 2:29], as.numeric))
```

but no luck in being able to run the `apply()` function successfully.
Am I sure I am just not reading the csv in properly or coercing them properly, but just can't get it right. Any tips? Please and thank you!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The row wise sum

```
apply(MSBees.spp, 1, sum)
```

is an issue because the first column based on the `str` is character.

```
$ X     : chr  "Site 1" "Site 2" "Site 3" "Site 4" ...
```

We need to exclude the first column

```
apply(MSBees.spp[-1], 1, sum)
```

and get the sum or use vectorized `rowSums`

```
rowSums(MSBees.spp[-1], na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Also, there is no need to reconvert the dataset to numeric as the data is correctly read as numeric column types.  In addition, `as.numeric` expects a vector as input where as `MSBees.spp` is a data.frame i.e. `as.numeric(MSBees.spp[[2]])` works as it is a vector